# How to Resize Form Contents Upon Form Resize (Special Case)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know there are several questions about this, but I can't seem to apply it to my case.

Here's a picture of my form:

[image]

When the form is re-sized (width made smaller), I want the highlighted controls to shrink in width appropriately so that the user could see all input fields when the form is re-sized (I'm a big fan of aero-snap, for example).

I've tried various combinations of panels, docks, anchors, etc, but I just can't seem to get appropriate settings. Could someone give me a suggestion on my case?

Comment: Are these in a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: No, they sure aren't. I designed this form a while ago without panels and such in mind, so they're currently free-floating. I've tried docking/anchoring them inside of a simple panel (can't achieve desired result with any combination of those properties that I've tried). I've also tried the FlowLayoutPanel for them but that simply moves them down vertically instead of resizing them.

Comment: Give that a shot then, it's designed to do exactly what you want.  Basically it's a grid of controls, and every "cell" can be set to fixed, percent, or auto sizing.  Gives you good control over self-resizing layouts.

Comment: If they are docked to all sides, they should shrink and grow with their container. Are you sure you tried that?